# How to install/use cbp2make for Code::Blocks?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, installation, codeblocks

I think this might be a very simple question but after looking around a lot I can't find the solution, perhaps due to just not understanding basic linux ideas or searching for the wrong kind of thing.

I am trying to install the cbp2make tool for Code::Blocks so that I can export a makefile (http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13675.0). I have downloaded the .tar.7z and extracted it to get a folder "cbp2make-stl-rev147-all" sitting in my Downloads folder. Where do I put this and what do I do next to actually use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the executable of `cpb2make` to `/usr/bin/`.

Next you can type in terminal smt like this : `cbp2make -in CODEBLOCKF.cbp -out makefile`